# Return a function (that returns a string) inside a function with kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to return a function (that returns a string) inside of function but, since I haven't made this explicit (I'm not sure how to make it so that the function knows it'll return a function), I get kotlin.Unit as a result.

This is the function:

```
fun takeOutArticle(code:String) {

       fun onSuccess(finalPrice: Int): String {
           return "Your price is $finalFee."
       }

       fun onError(): String {
           return "Error."
       }

       val articlesCode = house.articles.find{ it.code == code }
       if (articlesCode != null) {
           val finalPrice = calculatePrice(
               articleType = articlesCode.articleCode,
               finalTime = articlesCode.finalTime.toInt(),
               hasCard = !articlesCode.Card.isNullOrEmpty())

           onSuccess(finalPrice)
       } else {
           onError()
       }
```

So when I call the function and whether it's successful or not, it returns unit but I'd need it to return the string inside of onSuccess or onError. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to return a function, or *the value produced by inner function* ?

Comment: @amanin I'm basically trying to return the string produced by the inner function, but the function needs to exist (it was required for the task).

Comment: It's returning ``Unit`` because that's the default for a block function (where the body is in ``{ }``) and you're not ``return``ing a value. You're calling your functions and getting a ``String`` back, but you're not doing anything with them. You need to put ``return`` before those function calls (and then it will complain because you need to add ``String`` as the return type - it's expecting ``Unit`` by default remember, i.e. not returning anything)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. When returning a value from a function you have to specify the return type in function signature (after the name and arguments). Source: [Function syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#explicit-return-types).
2. Apart from lambdas, you need to add a return keyword in front of the return value / expression. Note that `if/else` is an expression.
3. Note that you can return the result of an inner function, but beware of your wording, because in Kotlin, you can also *return a reference to a function*

Example (you can execute it [here](https://pl.kotl.in/cDbiZ9BU0)) :

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun doStuff() : String {
    fun resultIfTrue() : String { return "Returns True" }
    fun resultIfFalse() : String { return "Returns False" }
    
    return if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
        resultIfTrue()
    } else {
        resultIfFalse()
    }
}

fun deferStuff() : () -> String {
    fun resultIfTrue() : String { return "Returns True"; }
    fun resultIfFalse() : String { return "Returns False"; }
    
    return if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
        ::resultIfTrue
    } else {
        ::resultIfFalse
    }
}

fun main() {
    println("Return result of inner function")
    for (i in 0 until 4) println(doStuff())
    println("Return inner function")
    for (i in 0 until 4) {
        val fn = deferStuff()
        println("Function returned another function: $fn that must be executed: ${fn()}")
    }
}
```

The above snippet prints:

```
Return result of inner function
Returns False
Returns False
Returns True
Returns True
Return inner function
Function returned another function: function resultIfFalse (Kotlin reflection is not available) that must be executed: Returns False
Function returned another function: function resultIfFalse (Kotlin reflection is not available) that must be executed: Returns False
Function returned another function: function resultIfFalse (Kotlin reflection is not available) that must be executed: Returns False
Function returned another function: function resultIfTrue (Kotlin reflection is not available) that must be executed: Returns True
```

You can see that the first half of the output shows directly the values that are produced by the inner functions, because they've been called from inside `doStuff` directly.

However, in the second case, where we've returned the inner function itself, it needs to be called by user (here the `main` function) later.